# table columns not getting sorted using tablesorter plugin

Tags: javascript, html, tablesorter

Below is the format of my html page:

```html
<table id = 'myTable' class='table table-striped tablesorter'>
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Wild</th>
         <th>Release Date</th>
         <th>CVE</th>
         <th>QH Detection Name</th>
         <th>Comments</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tr class='info'>
     <td width='3%'><img src='ex.png' alt='' border=3 height=25 width=25></img></td>
     <td width='10%'>03/11/2015</td>
     <td width='12%'>CVE-2015-1623</td>
     <td width='17%'>
         <li>abc</li>
         <li>xyz</li>
         <li>pqr</li>
         </ul>
     </td>
     <td width='58%'>
         <b>Description: </b><br>Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a denial of service (memory corruption) via a crafted web site, aka "Internet Explorer Memory Corruption Vulnerability".
         VPS release: 150311-00
         <br><b>Link: </b><br> 
         <ul>
             <li><a href =http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-1623 target ='_blank'>http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-1623<br></a></li>
         </ul>
     </td>
 </tr>
 .......
</table>
```

JS page:

```html
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[1,0],[2,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

I am using table sorter plugin, however table is not getting sorted.
I am using tablesorter plugin first time and I did the way mentioned in doc of tablesorter,  however its not working

Comment: Did you checked the error in console?

Comment: sorting is not happning, even I want to sort on clicking header of column

Comment: The first block of javascript is not needed. Could you make a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Thanks for your attention , actually the problem was the older version of tablesorter, downloaded newer version and problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

As @doveyg stated, the first block of script is not needed. In fact, because tablesorter had already been initialized on that table, the options included in second block of code will be completely ignored, which is why the table isn't sorting.

All you need is:

```
$(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[1,0],[2,0]] } ); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention , actually the problem was the older version of tablesorter, downloaded newer version and problem resolved